# How to get post thumbnail URL manually in wordpress plugin development?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I want to get post thumbnail url manually without using this code

```
wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );
```

For example using MySQL query.Its possible?

Comment: Why want you do this, when there's an easy to use method?

Comment: yes. but i want show multiple website posts in single site using custom plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This MySql Query

```
 SELECT
        p1.*,
        wm2.meta_value
    FROM 
        wp_posts p1
    LEFT JOIN 
        wp_postmeta wm1
        ON (
            wm1.post_id = p1.id 
            AND wm1.meta_value IS NOT NULL
            AND wm1.meta_key = "_thumbnail_id"              
        )
    LEFT JOIN 
        wp_postmeta wm2
        ON (
            wm1.meta_value = wm2.post_id
            AND wm2.meta_key = "_wp_attached_file"
            AND wm2.meta_value IS NOT NULL  
        )
    WHERE
        p1.post_status="publish" 
        AND p1.post_type="post"
    ORDER BY 
        p1.post_date DESC
```

Comment: I am using this concept only. thanks for your answer.